# Pie chart in ggplot2 with different sections apart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a pie chart in ggplot2 like the figure below. Each section of pie is separated.

[image]

Now I want use ggplot2 to make a similar figure.

```
a = c("cell","cell part","response to stimulus")
b = c('155','166','100')
tmp = as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
ggplot(tmp2, aes(x=a,y=b, fill=a)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + scale_fill_brewer(palette='Dark2') + coord_polar(start=0)
```

The figure I got is like this:
[image]

The radius of each section is not equal. I hope someone could help me find out how to make radius equal.